# Void Buffer Incorrectly Referenced Still Works

Tags: linux, system-calls, void, dereference

While I was working on a bit of C code, I came across this strange bug.

I made a mistake in my code and wrote to `buf` rather than `&buf`, but it worked *almost* just fine.

```c
...
void* buf;
int ret;

int fd = open("1", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777);
write(fd, "test\n", 5);
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
ret = read(fd, buf, 5);                 // Yes, this should be &buf
printf("Ret: %d Str: %s\n", ret, buf);
---- output ----
Ret: 5 Str: test\n
```

This code works and I get `test\n` in my stdout, even though I should have had `&buf` in my read call. Please, I am aware that changing `buf` to `&buf` works. That is not the question.

This is what does not work:

```c
...
void* buf;
void* blah = "a";     // Using char* still did not work
int ret;

int fd = open("1", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777);
write(fd, "test\n", 5);
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
ret = read(fd, buf, 5);
printf("Ret: %d Str: %s\n", ret, buf);
---- output ----
Ret: -1 Str: 1�I��^H��H���PTI��`@
```

The binary for file `1` is the same for both programs. No error in writing to `1`.

- Why does the first code snippet work?
- How does adding a variable that is never used make this no longer
  work?
- Why did writing to `buf` and not `&buf` work in the first place?

Here is the strings section in each binary:

Functioning code:

```c
0000770: 0100 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000780: 3100 7465 7374 0a00 4572 723a 2025 640a  1.test..Err: %d.
0000790: 0a00 5374 723a 2025 730a 0000 011b 033b  ..Str: %s......;
00007a0: 3000 0000 0500 0000 34fd ffff 7c00 0000  0.......4...|...
```

Malfunctioning code:

```c
0000770: 0100 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000780: 6100 3100 7465 7374 0a00 4572 723a 2025  a.1.test..Err: %
0000790: 640a 0a00 5374 723a 2025 730a 0000 0000  d...Str: %s.....
00007a0: 011b 033b 3400 0000 0500 0000 30fd ffff  ...;4.......0...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Unless there's more code you didn't show, neither of those "work" because your buf pointer doesn't actually point to anything meaningful, meaning attempting to read into it is undefined and anything could happen. You don't get a warning about that? If you're not compiling with a decent set of warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang (And you should add Asan (`-fsanitize=address`)) too while you're at it), do so, and **pay attention** to them..

Comment: And no, that shouldn't be `&buf` unless you're trying to make that variable point to an address read from a file (which you're not, and shouldn't be doing)

Comment: Hi Shawn. The only code I removed was the `int main() { ... }`. I am not reading from the void pointer. I am reading from the file `1` and placing it into `buf`, which is what is being done and what I want to be done. As for those warnings, no, I do not receive any warnings other than setting a `void*` with `%s` in my printf statement with the `-Wall -Wextra` tags. The `void* buf` is also the recognized input for read, as shown [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/read). That is where I followed this. EDIT: Please note the return value for the read function. There is no error the first time.

Answer (score 0):

(Since it's pretty much impossible to put more than a line of code in comments)

Warnings from compiling with `-Wall -Wextra`:

```
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:15:25: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘void *’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("Ret: %d Str: %s\n", ret, buf);
                        ~^
                        %p
x.c:14:9: warning: ‘buf’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   ret = read(fd, buf, 5);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The results of running your program through valgrind:

```
==6978== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6978== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6978== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6978== Command: ./a.out
==6978== 
==6978== Syscall param read(buf) contains uninitialised byte(s)
==6978==    at 0x4F4C081: read (read.c:27)
==6978==    by 0x1087BF: main (x.c:14)
==6978== 
==6978== Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==6978==    at 0x4F4C081: read (read.c:27)
==6978==    by 0x1087BF: main (x.c:14)
==6978==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6978== 
==6978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6978==    at 0x4E97A41: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1643)
==6978==    by 0x4EA0F25: printf (printf.c:33)
==6978==    by 0x1087DC: main (x.c:18)
==6978== 
Ret: -1 Str: (null)
==6978== 
==6978== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6978==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6978==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==6978== 
==6978== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6978== 
==6978== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6978== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==6978== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

You have to make `buf` point to valid memory you have permission to use or you get undefined behavior where anything can happen. If you're lucky, it'll just crash your program, but you can't count on that.